# Android Studio If-statement make TextView visible if invisible and invisible if visible

Tags: java, android-studio, if-statement, textview, visibility

I am trying to make a textView invisible when pressing a button. But, if the textView is already invisible I want it to become visible.

Currently I am trying sonething like this:

```
public void ShowAndHide(View view){
    if(textView == View.VISIBLE){
        textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else   {
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Where "textView" is a TextView which I have defined by id:

```
TextView textView;

textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showMe_txt);
```

Anyone who knows why this does not work? Coming from a C# background and this is my first dabble with Java so quite unfamiliar.

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be `if(textView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot seem to upvote your comment just yet (this is literally my first post), however this did solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: This can be left as a comment as it is not an answer :)